# C++14 no visible after installing xeus-cling in Jupyter (Ubuntu 18.04 - Anaconda)

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, environment-variables, jupyter, xeus-cling

I followed the installation of the xeus-cling (created an env, activated,installed xeus-cling there) and when I want to select the C++14 kernel in a jupyter notebook it only appears Python3. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What instructions did you follow? How do you attempt to "select the C++14 kernel"? How does Python3 "appears"? Also please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Hi, I followed https://github.com/jupyter-xeus/xeus-cling guide for installation. When I create a jupyter notebook, it doesnt appear the c++14 option. Only Python3.

Comment: The easiest fix is probably to install Jupyter Notebook in the same environment. Then make sure you activate that environment before you start Jupyter.

Comment: Yeah @darthbith, I was using default Jupyter! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Its because jupyter-notebook is not installed in your environment. The jupyter server which is starting is the global one hence you don't see the `c++14` option. The solution is:

1. Create a new directory and git clone the repository.
2. Run the `conda env create -f environmental.yml` command in cmd.
3. Run the `conda activate xeus-cling` command.
4. Run the `jupyter notebook` command.

You should now be able to see the c++14 and c++17 options. Step 2 created the `xeus-cling` environment and installs all the correct package versions including the correct jupyter notebook version.

Answer (score 0):

Install notebook in your environment.

```
conda install xeus-cling notebook -c QuantStack -c conda-forge
```

Comment: `conda install notebook` in the cling conda environment is enough.

Answer (score 0):

You need [register new kernels in jupyter](https://xeus-cling.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#installing-the-kernel-spec):

```
jupyter kernelspec install PREFIX/share/jupyter/xcpp11 --sys-prefix
jupyter kernelspec install PREFIX/share/jupyter/xcpp14 --sys-prefix
jupyter kernelspec install PREFIX/share/jupyter/xcpp17 --sys-prefix
```